# Why MySQL is changing the column name with value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece of code written somewhere in PHP:

```
$sql="UPDATE drivers ".
"SET Location=$lo ".
"WHERE DriverId=$id";

echo $sql;
```

The outcome of echo is

> UPDATE drivers SET Location=locA WHERE DriverId=3

However when I run

```
$result = mysqli_query($con2,$sql);
echo $result;
echo mysqli_error($con2);
```

I get

> Unknown column 'locA' in 'field list'

Why am I getting 'locA' instead of Location as column name ?

Comment: $lo gets the value locA by POST methord in php

Comment: @relentless it is `locA` as shown in the output, which is lacking the quotes needed to insert a string.

Comment: I mean, what is it's value?

Comment: Use prepared statements, it will solve your problem and avoid sql injection.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

locA is a string and needs to be quoted.

```
$sql="UPDATE drivers ".
"SET Location='$lo' ".
"WHERE DriverId=$id";
```

You should look into using PDO and prepared statements to do the quoting for you.

Comment: `mysqli` can do this as well, but you need to prepare and execute in two separate steps.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put `$lo` inside single quotes:

```
$sql="UPDATE drivers ".
"SET Location='$lo' ".
"WHERE DriverId='$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

At least you must

$sql="UPDATE drivers ".
"SET Location='$lo' ".
"WHERE DriverId=$id";

but go to mysqli and use prepared statements instead. If you do what I suggest you are wide open to SQL-injections.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is trying to evaluate locA as a field as it's not a string value. Try something more like:

```
$sql="UPDATE drivers ".
"SET Location='".$lo."' ".
"WHERE DriverId=$id";
```

Which should result in:

UPDATE drivers SET Location='locA' WHERE DriverId=3

PDO and prepared statements would be the way to go though as others have mentioned.